# nodejs mongodb findAndModify exception: E11000 duplicate key error index

Tags: node.js, mongodb

monogodb databse:

```
 { "title" : "A vs B ha",
      "status" : 1,
      "items" : [ 
        { "name" : "0",
          "num" : 0,
          "men" : [ 
            { "user" : "id1",
              "score" : 300 }, 
            { "user" : "id2",
              "score" : 1300 }, 
            { "user" : "id3",
              "score" : 400 } ] }, 
        { "name" : "1",
          "num" : 0,
          "men" : [ 
            { "user" : "id11",
              "score" : 3300 }, 
            { "user" : "id23",
              "score" : 13400 }, 
            { "user" : "id3",
              "score" : 4000 } ] }, 
        { "name" : "2",
          "num" : 0,
          "men" : [] } ],
      "_id" : ObjectId( "538db59fa332f765c0f2c210" ) }
```

This Node.js code doesn't work:

```
collection.findAndModify(
{"_id": idSearch
,"items.name":sBetItem,"items.men.user":sUser}
,[]
, {
  $set:{
      "items.men.user":sUser}
  ,$inc: { "items.men.score": sScore }
}
, {new:true, upsert:true}

,function(err, docUser) {
  if (err){
      console.warn(err.message);  // returns error if no matching object found
  }else{
      console.dir(docUser);
  }

});
```

I want to search a player's score, if it doesn't exist, insert new;
if it already exist, increase his score number. 
But it has error:exception: E11000 duplicate key error index

Comment: Have you copied the full error message? Is there no index name after `E11000 duplicate key error index` ?

Comment: `exception: E11000 duplicate key error index: g1bet.lists.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('538e1588b3867927cbc1dba6') }
`This is the error

Comment: I changed to use mongoose. Can Someone please answer my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075910/mongoose-cant-update-or-insert-subdocuments-array